# Elastic Beanstalk connect to Azure Sql Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

everyone.

I'm trying connect from Elastic Beanstalk Environment (Load Balanced) to Azure SQL Databases.
In Azure Portal I can assign static IP of EC2 instance from Elastic Load Balanced Member. But as you know, ec2 ip addresses can change or their count can increase or decrease depend on workload.
I want to bind all ec2 static ip addresses to AZURE SQL Server firewall for future access.
Need your advises and opinions, how to do this.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a static IP for your Elastic Beanstalk environment. In order to accomplish this, you must do the following:

1. Create a VPC with one ore more public subnets and one ore more private subnets. Attach an Internet Gateway to the VPC to have internet connectivity for the public subnets
2. Place a NAT gateway in one of your public subnet and assign an [Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) to it
3. Route the outgoing traffic from the private subnets to the NAT gateway. This means that everyone from the outside will see the IP address of the NAT gateway. Information about routing can be found in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html)
4. Deploy your Elastic Beanstalk environment in your private subnets with the load balancer in the public subnet. To accomplish this, follow the steps from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) AWS support page.